# Is there a better way to update some object in array which represents state for React component?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have the following `React` component (this is just an example):

```
class MainForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       elements : [
         {
           id: 1, // this is never changed
           title: 'Element 1',
           data: {
              text: 'Initial text for Element 1',
              // other properties 
              ...
           }
         },
         .....
       ]
    };
  }
}
```

The `state` here is an array of objects (like the one in my code). All elements in the array have `id` and this property is never changed!

I would like to update this array - remove elements, add new elements and the most interesting - **update some existing elements** in that array.

Add/Remove are easy to implement, but I got stuck with the update of the existing items.

I am new to React so here is my approach and it is probably a little expensive:

```
updateElements = value => {
  // value is the object with some property updated
  /* example (data.text is updated)
      {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Element 1',
        data: {
          text: 'Updated text for Element 1',
          // other properties 
          ...
        }
      }   
    */

  // there is 'id' for each item so I do map to replace out-dated element with a new one
  const updatedElements = this.state.elements.
            .map(e => {
                if (e.id === value.id) {
                    return value;
                } else {
                    return e;
                }
            });

  this.setState({
    elements: updatedElements  
  });        
}
```

This array in my case can be pretty big as well as objects stored in it.

There has to be a more efficient way to do it with either React or pure JavaScript to make it perform better.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This is a JS question and has nothing to do with React. Please take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex

Answer (score 1):

Nope, you got it.

The best way to edit an item in an array in state is typically to map over it, return the existing item for most indexes, and return your replacement item with the one index you want.

You say this is "very expensive" but a map that does very little processing and returns a new array that is mainly made up of references to objects that already exist is not typically expensive in any way.

If you don't want to do this kind of juggling, immutable data libraries like [Immutable.js](https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/) and others can help.